# Django: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: django, django-templates

When I'm trying render template after login I get

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'update' with
>   keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['users/(?P[0-9]+)/update/$']

My line in urls.py:

```
app_name="users"
...

path("users/<int:pk>/update/", view=user_update_view, name="update"),
```

And line in template:

```
<a href="{% url 'users:update' pk=request.user.pk %}">Update user</a>
```

I see that **request.user.pk** not giving value, but I don't know why.

Comment: It looks like your `request.user` has not a `pk`. For example because it is an `AnonymousUser` (if the user is not logged in).

Comment: I see. But problem is, I logged in. When I login by my form, authentication work because I'm also logged in into django admin site.

Comment: try removing  `request`, use `pk=user.pk` instead

Comment: @Yellowduck didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to prevent this happening while user is not logged in write

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{% url 'users:update' %}">Update user</a>
{% else %}
 <p> user not logged in </p> or whatever you want!!
{% endif %}
```

I think it is not good idea to update currently logged in user by passing id in url parameter. if someone intentially type other id in address bar then he/ she can update anyone's profile. so rather than doing this chnage your url as below.
`path("users/update/", view=user_update_view, name="update"),` and in your views

```
@login_required
def user_update_view(request):
    user= User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

    # whatever you want!!
```

Comment: It's weird because, when I login by my form, I'm logged in to admin site, but in this view user isn't autheticated.

Comment: Any ideas, what I should do, to fix that?

Comment: I have DetailView for User where I'm redirected when login. There I have some links, including this with redirect to UpdateView for logged user. This template is only show when User is logged in.

Comment: When I test it locally, it's working, but I deploy on digitalocean to check if in production will work and it isn't.